# tkinter python: How do remove the input cursor from a ttk.Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have an instance of ttk.Entry. 
The user clicks it.
I have the event bound.
Depending on some condition, I either want the input cursor to appear and allow typing *or* I essentially want to ignore the click and not have the input cursor appear in the ttk.Entry. I *don't* want to have to use the readonly or disabled states.

Manipulating focus has not effect.

Comment: Why don't you "want to have to use the readonly or disabled states"?  Knowing this may help us give a better answer.

Comment: They change the appearance of the widget - which is not acceptable for my purposes :-(

Comment: @sjjg:  `Entry.config(state=DISABLED)` doesn't have to change the appearance of your widget.  Just set the colors of `disabledbackground` and `disabledforground` to match the colors of `background` and `forground`.

Comment: By “cursor”, do you mean the marker used to indicate where insertion will happen or the pointer that is coupled to the mouse?

Comment: @Donal: from context I believe he means the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trawling the ttk documentation, this does the trick:

```
    ttk.Style().map("TEntry",
                    foreground=[('disabled', 'black')],
                    fieldbackground=[('disabled','white')]
                    )
    widget['state'] = 'disabled'
```

Comment: Which is documented quite nicely here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that does what you ask.

```
class MyEntry(Entry):

    def disable(self):
        self.__old_insertontime = self.cget('insertontime')
        self.config(insertontime=0)
        self.bind('<Key>', lambda e: 'break')

    def enable(self):
        self.unbind('<Key>')
        if self.cget('insertontime') == 0:
            self.config(insertontime=self.__old_insertontime)
```

However, since your real concern is that you don't want a disabled Entry to look disabled, just set the colors of `disabledbackground` and `disabledforground` to match the colors of `background` and `forground`.  If you need this rolled into a class, do it like this:

```
class MyEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.config(disabledbackground=self.cget('background'))
        self.config(disabledforeground=self.cget('foreground'))
```

And use it like this:

```
e = MyEntry(root)
e.config(state=DISABLED) # or state=NORMAL
```

**Note.**  Be careful when reinventing gui conventions.  Having something that looks enabled act disabled can be confusing for users.  So don't change this unless you have good reason.

Comment: I'm using tkinter.ttk.Entry rather than tkinter.Entry, so the solution is not exactly this. You were correct with modifying the disabled state of the widget though - thanks!

Comment: I'm investigating UI issues, so being able to play with them is very useful.